# Routes for same component with nested others

Tags: routes, nested, components, angular

After hours of researches and tests, I come here to maybe found a solution.

So, I explain my problem.

For example, I have a component "WikisComponent".
Inside him, I call a "CategoriesComponent" to display all categories (from a API).
Inside the WikisComponent, I have the list of them.
Inside the WikisComponent, I have a WikiDetailComponent (when user click on one of the list).

Here a diagram :
[image: Schema 0]

So, when I click on a row of the wikis table, interface looks like :
[image: Schema 1]

All this system work. But, if I switch to a new wiki with a `router.navigate`, it reload my wikis table too. (Already loaded before).

For example if I had a route
`/wikis` => Display wikis table (with categories list).
And `/wikis/my-super-wiki`, if I set `routerLink=Wikis/WikiDetail`, it reload my wikis table.

I don't know if you need more precision, it's very difficult to explain my problem.
And sorry for my bad english !

Thanks !

**EDIT** :

There is my WikisComponent (my RootComponent) :

```
import {Component, Input} from "angular2/core";
import {RouteConfig, RouterOutlet, RouterLink} from "angular2/router";

import {WikisIndexComponent} from "./components/index";

@Component({
    selector: 'wikis-component',
    template: `
         <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="" [routerLink]="['/Invoices/InvoicesCreate']" class="btn btn-success">Ajouter un wiki</a>
        </div>

        <h3 class="page-header">Wikis</h3>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', component: WikisIndexComponent, name: 'WikisIndex', useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/:slug', component: WikisIndexComponent, name: 'WikiDetail'},
])
export class WikisComponent{
}
```

And this is the wikis index component (it include the table, not usefull here) :

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {RouteParams, Router} from "angular2/router";
import {WikisService} from "../services/wikis";
import {WikisListComponent} from "./partials/list";
import {WikiShowComponent} from "./partials/show";
import {WikisCategoriesListComponent} from "../categories/components/list";

@Component({
    selector: 'wikis-index',
    template: `
         <wikis-categories class="col-md-2"></wikis-categories>

         <div class="col-md-10">
            <div [class.col-md-12]="!slugWikiSelected" [class.col-md-3]="slugWikiSelected">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">     
                        <h5>
                            Liste des wikis <small>({{wikis?.length}})</small>
                        </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body panel-body-no-padding">
                        <wikis-list *ngIf="wikis" (wikiSelectedEvent)="setWikiSelected($event)" [wikis]="wikis"></wikis-list>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9" *ngIf="slugWikiSelected">
                <wiki-show [wikiSlug]="slugWikiSelected" (unselectWikiEvent)="wikiSelected = null"></wiki-show>
            </div>
        </div>
        `,
    directives: [WikisListComponent, WikiShowComponent, WikisCategoriesListComponent]
})
export class WikisIndexComponent{
    private wikis;
    private slugWikiSelected;

    constructor(private _routeParams: RouteParams, private _wikisService: WikisService, private _router: Router){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        let slug = this._routeParams.get('slug');

        if(slug){
            this.slugWikiSelected = slug;
        }

        this.getAllWikis();
    }

    getAllWikis(){
        this._wikisService.all().subscribe(res => this.wikis = res.data);
    }

    setWikiSelected(wiki){
        this._router.navigate(['/Wikis/WikiDetail', {slug : wiki.slug}]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks Gunter, I've past my main code.

Comment: I have troubles understanding what this means "Cause I don't know what I need to do to set a router from the same "RootComponent" but without reload everyting." Why is it a problem if you give an URL to a friend and everything is reloaded?

Comment: Hmm yeah, your alright. I explain better (edited just after). If I change the current wiki to display the detail, I call _router.navigate() (with the new wiki slug), and at this moment, it reload everything in the main component.

Comment: Where do you call this `_router.navigate()` and with what parameters? I couldn't find it in your code.

Comment: Sorry guy. I updated my code for a better comprehension. (My last edit intercept many tests, my bad)

Comment: Your above prose explanation doesn't include a `WikiIndexComponent`. Is this the `WikisComponent`?

Comment: The first file is the WikisComponenet (root), and the second is the WikisIndexComponent. What's wrong ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess

```
routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) { return true; }
```

is what you want, while `return true;` might vary on some criterias.
If `true` is returned the component is reused instead of recreated.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html

Comment: Thanks guy, this is exactly what I want !!